# Casting to a shared_ptr* from a void*

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, undefined-behavior, void-pointers, static-cast

I have a shared pointer that, due to interactions with a C library, spends part of its life as a `void*`

```
class Base { };

class Derived : public Base { };

int main() {
  // Construct the object.
  std::shared_ptr<Derived> derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();

  // Make a void* that I can pass into the C library.
  std::shared_ptr<Derived>* derived_ptr = new std::shared_ptr<Derived>(derived);
  void* my_void = derived_ptr;

  // Cast back into a shared_ptr when I get the void* from the C library
  std::shared_ptr<Base> base = *static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Base>* >(my_void);
}
```

My worry is that I could cause undefined behavior, because I am casting to `std::shared_ptr<Base>*` when I receive the `void*` back from the C library, rather than casting to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>*`.  I think that this would be safe if I were storing only a C-style pointer, but I don't know how inheritance and casting work with shared pointers.

Unfortunately, with the way my program is currently structured, when I am reading the `void*` out of the C library, I have no knowledge of the derived class, and so I can't just cast to `std::shared_ptr<Derived>*`, which I know would be safe.

Is it safe to use the casts as they are currently shown, for any possible combination of `Base` and `Derived` classes, or are there circumstances in which the result is not defined?

Comment: Why are you `new`'ing up the `shared_ptr` instead of just using `&derived`? And no, I don't think that the cast is safe. But wouldn't it be better anyway to just pass `derived.get()` to the C function? What can it do with the smart pointer?

Comment: Firstly, you *cannot* simply cast a `void*` to a `std::shared_ptr` - it's a whole class in its own right and cannot be treated as something that you can arbitrarly cast raw pointers to. Now, in order to answer your question, please explain what sort of pointer ownership the C code takes (e.g. exclusive, non-exclusive) and whether your code or the C code is responsible for freeing the object.

Comment: The particular library being used is the Lua interpreter.  The `new` is there so that the lifetime of the Derived object is maintained either by a `shared_ptr` existing in C++ code, or by a reference existing in Lua code.  The `new std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is owned exclusively by the Lua interpreter.  The interpreter also takes a callback, and so once the Lua interpreter is done using the object, it enters the callback, calling `delete` on the `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` that was previously `new`-ed.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. It's OK to cast any pointer to `void*` and then back to the original type - but it's undefined behavior to cast to a different type. This round-trip through `void*` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast< std::shared_ptr<Base>* >(derived_ptr)`, casting a pointer to an unrelated type. This has nothing to do with `shared_ptr` - it's equally wrong for any pair of types. E.g. this too exhibits undefined behavior: `Derived* pd = new Derived; void* pv = pd; Base* pb = static_cast<Base*>(pv);` (equivalent to `Base* pb = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(pd);`)